# Invokable controller in non-default namespace (LARAVEL 8) - error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a single action controller that is in App\Http\Controllers\Api\TestController; not default namespace.

I tried to invoke that method but it gives me this error:

> *"message": "Invalid route action: [Api\App\Http\Controllers\Api\TestController].", "exception":
> "UnexpectedValueException", "file":
> "/Users/macbook/Projects/laravel/digitalorganigrama_hr/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteAction.php",*'
>
> ....
>
> Api\App\Http\Controllers\Api\TestController`was not found: Controller class`Api\App\Http\Controllers\Api\TestController`for one of your routes was not found. Did you mean`App\Http\Controllers\Api\TestController`?

In the route/api.php i have:

`Route::get('/test',  ContractNormController::class)`;

TestController.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Here is your answer: https://laraveldaily.com/invokable-controllers-with-one-specific-action/

Comment: I know how to do it. But I get an error where my controller is not in the default namespace.

Comment: I solved it. 
The problem was because I had an unnecessary Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api'],...) in api.php. Api namespace is by default in api.php.